# How to avoid rounded integer while converting from string with decimal point to NUMERIC.?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, integer

I have tried to converting from string with decimal point to NUMERIC. While converting this, I got the integer value as round off. I don't want to get that integer as round off value.

**Case 1:**
For Example:

```
DECLARE @val varchar(10);
SET @val = 454.6;
SELECT (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC( CAST( @val AS VARCHAR(MAX) ) ) = 1 THEN
CAST( CAST( @val AS VARCHAR(MAX) ) AS NUMERIC ) ELSE NULL END)
```

if i run this, I will get the value as rounded integer as **455**.

But I need the  value as **454** by avoiding rounded integer.

**Case 2**:

If i convert this value from string to integer, i got an issue as below:

**Error: SQLSTATE[22018]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '454.6' to data type int.**

Please let me know if anyone having idea on this,

Thanks,
Matheswaran.S
[image]
[image]

Comment: it seems like you need `MSQL` and not `MYSQL`

Comment: hi @VijunavVastivch, yes its for MSSQL

Answer (score 1):

You can use FLOOR function to capture the integer part of a Decimal as:

```
DECLARE @val varchar(10);
SET @val = 454.6;
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC( CAST( @val AS VARCHAR(MAX) ) ) = 1 
        THEN FLOOR(CAST( CAST( @val AS VARCHAR(MAX) ) AS DECIMAL(18, 3) ) )
        ELSE NULL END
```

Or... with this way is the same and a bit more compact:

```
DECLARE @val varchar(10) = '454.6';
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC( CAST( @val AS VARCHAR(MAX) ) ) = 1 
        THEN FLOOR(CAST(@val AS DECIMAL(18, 3) ) )
        ELSE NULL END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @val varchar(10);
SET @val = 454.6;

select  Cast([decimal] as int) from
(select convert(decimal(10,4), @val) as decimal) as a
```